# Do we have to build the heap again after insert?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, heap

I have a question about the insert operation in heap. Reading it about it says it is in O(logn), but when I saw this implementation:

```
void max_insert(int* max_heap, int size, int elm) {
    if (size == 0) {
        max_heap[0] = elm;
    } 
    else {
        max_heap[size] = elm;
        for (int i = size / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          max_heapify(max_heap, size, i);
    }
    size += 1;
}
```

Assuming `max_heapify` is done in O(logn), this insert is actually done in O(n), which is equivalent to building a heap, but why one would build the entire heap after an insert to the heap? This insert implementation looks wrong to me, is that right?

This is the max_heapify from the same implementation:

```
void max_heapify(int* max_heap, int size, int i) {
    if (size > 1) {
        int largest = i, left = 2 * i + 1, right = 2 * i + 2;
        if (left < size && max_heap[left] > max_heap[largest])
          largest = l;
        if (right < size && max_heap[right] > max_heap[largest])
          largest = right;
        if (largest != i) {
          swap(&max_heap[i], &max_heap[largest]);
          max_heapify(max_heap, size, largest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a bad, inefficient implementation of `max_insert` and with this you would lose the benefit of using a heap.

Comment: exactly, it was bizarre really. Thank you

Comment: Looks like max_insert is O(nlog(n)) @user21078706